# how to work with the project ignite web console provides?

Tags: intellij-idea, ignite

I have a ignite cluster setup. There is a postgres database which has a schema. I have imported that schema into ignite. All the table names have been appended with the work 'Cache'. For e.g. `Account -> AccountCache`

If I play around with the console, and, inspect my ImportedCluster (which is the default name for what is imported) I can see a link below the screen to see the project structure. Here I am presented with a dialog where I can see the project structure.

Using the `Save and Download` option (i.e. the blue button called 'Save') in the pic below, I can download that project. How do I run this project in intellij IDE?

[image]

---

Update:

In the intellij ide, I figured out how to setup the maven project. And from the maven projects window, I clicked on install > Run maven build, as shown in the pic.

[image]

Here is the output it gave:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=D:\code\java-intellij\ignite-project "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.6\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.6\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.6\lib\idea_rt.jar=53750:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.6\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.6\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2018.2.6 install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ImportedCluster-project 2.7.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/ignite/ignite-core/2.7.0/ignite-core-2.7.0.pom
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.ignite:ignite-core:jar:2.7.0 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/ignite/ignite-spring/2.7.0/ignite-spring-2.7.0.pom
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.ignite:ignite-spring:jar:2.7.0 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/ignite/ignite-indexing/2.7.0/ignite-indexing-2.7.0.pom
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.ignite:ignite-indexing:jar:2.7.0 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/ignite/ignite-rest-http/2.7.0/ignite-rest-http-2.7.0.pom
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.ignite:ignite-rest-http:jar:2.7.0 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/ignite/ignite-core/2.7.0/ignite-core-2.7.0.jar
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/ignite/ignite-spring/2.7.0/ignite-spring-2.7.0.jar
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/ignite/ignite-indexing/2.7.0/ignite-indexing-2.7.0.jar
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/ignite/ignite-rest-http/2.7.0/ignite-rest-http-2.7.0.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 18.876 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-11-24T08:20:59+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/85M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ImportedCluster-project: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.ignite:ImportedCluster-project:jar:2.7.0: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.ignite:ignite-core:jar:2.7.0, org.apache.ignite:ignite-spring:jar:2.7.0, org.apache.ignite:ignite-indexing:jar:2.7.0, org.apache.ignite:ignite-rest-http:jar:2.7.0: Could not find artifact org.apache.ignite:ignite-core:jar:2.7.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Is it that the 2.7.0 version binaries are unavailable?

Here is the current pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- This file was generated by Ignite Web Console (11/23/2018, 14:12) -->

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
    <artifactId>ImportedCluster-project</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-indexing</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-rest-http</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.1212.jre7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-libs</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludeGroupIds>org.apache.ignite</excludeGroupIds>
                            <outputDirectory>target/libs</outputDirectory>
                            <includeScope>compile</includeScope>
                            <excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Above pom.xml file, you have entered ignite version 2.7 which is not available on central maven repository. So used 2.6 version and try.

Below is the procedure to start Ignite Web Console.

Follow the steps for Ignite web agent setup:-

1)If you have known IP address then select Discovery:- **Static** and add IP address

2)Open command prompt and run the script **ignite-web-agent.sh** which is present in downloaded package

3)After successful connection between web-agent and Ignite you can check on web agent console's Dashboard for your Ignite cluster

Answer (score 0):

What you see in the screenshot isn't really "project structure." Instead it's the configuration file for starting Ignite with that list of caches and a connection to your PostgreSQL database.

Creating a client app to connect to that Ignite cluster basically involves [following the steps in the documentation](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/getting-started). In short:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
  <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
  <version>${ignite.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
  <artifactId>ignite-spring</artifactId>
  <version>${ignite.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
  <artifactId>ignite-indexing</artifactId>
  <version>${ignite.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you can connect to the cluster using the same configuration file.

Comment: I have updated the question post. I suspect that there is some issue with v2.7.0 binaries.